# "Atrapar" name de un textbox en html con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una tabla donde está un textbox que se incrementa dependiendo del resultado de la consulta, lo que quiero es atrapar el name con el bucle for :

```
<input type="text" name="tname" value="1"> 
<input type="text" name="tname" value="2">
<input type="text" name="tname" value="3"> 
<input type="text" name="tname" value="4">
```

Comment: edita tu pregunta por que con esas etiquetas inputs no se entiende NADA de tu duda

Comment: Hola Leonardo! No queda muy claro lo que quieres lograr, tal vez si agregas lo que has intentado se aclare un poco lo que quieres y obtengas una respuesta. Para mas información puedes revisar [ask]

Comment: Creo que es agregandole esto . var i for (i=0;i<=tname; i++) { } , pero no se bien la sintaxis, para que cada vez que aparezca n cantidad de veces el tname se le asigne un valor.

Answer (score 0):

Era esto lo que necesitaba:

```js
$(function() {
    var values = $('input[name="text[]"]').map(function() {
        return this.value
    }).get()
    console.log(values)
})
```

Lo conseguí aquí: http://jsfiddle.net/UugWW/690/ , estoy seguro que no pregunté bien lo que quería.